# I have an xml file outside webcontent(Eclipse). I need to access it using href.

Tags: html, eclipse

This is the path of my xml file
C:\Workspace\Auto\src\com\TestSuite\chacha.xml

Here Auto is my project name in eclipse and TestSuite is a folder under com which contains the xml file.

the link works well when i use internal browser but the path even if i give absolute path is not recognized by IE or chrome.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Eclipse project, and select `Properties`.  From there, select `Deployment Assembly`.  Add the folder `TestSuite` and it should now be included with your build.

(This assumes that your project is setup as a Dynamic Web Project)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i am trying to add TestSuite, it says the folder already exists... But when trying to access the link it gives the error message access denied... Please help!!!